# passing variable from static inner class to top class

Tags: java, mapreduce

So I want to set the value of my top classes variable, foo, from within my static nested class. My end goal here is to figure out how to pass an argument from the Map method to the Reduce method in a MapReduce program I am writing. I simplified the code to only it's necessary elements for readability.

Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    static String top = "foo";

    public void setTop(String newValue) {
        this.top = newValue;
    }

    public static class InnerClass {
        String innerString = "bar";
        Ideone newOne = new Ideone();
        newOne.setTop(innerString ); //not legal

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World " + top);
    }
}
```

In an actual MapReduce program, the nested class would be my Mapper, and the top level class would be the name of the overall MapReduce program which I will eventually Jar and run across my Hadoop cluster.

Comment: Either don't make your inner class "static", or pass in a the Ideone class into InnerClass.

Comment: Surely the issue is that you're trying to run procedural code outside of a method?

Comment: I hope your solution considers the following: In case of a map reduce program, the code execution will be distributed (it will run in multiple JVM's on different machines). Also, there is no guarantee that the reduce step will reuse the same object instance created for reduction.

Comment: @MJSG, you raise a valid concern. I am in fact trying to pass an argument from Mapper to Partitioner, which is executed before distribution across the cluster to the Reducer(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the static inner class and not the nested class. Its the class itself - This one will work:

```
public static class InnerClass {
    String innerString = "bar";
    Ideone newOne = new Ideone();
    {
       newOne.setTop(innerString ); //not legal
    }

}
```

Or place the call to `setTop` in the constructor. The syntax you chose in your example is simply invalid.

**Another hint:** It is not clear why you have a static variable top, that has a non-static setter, that is called from another class by constructing a dummy, that calls the setter. Why not simply `Ideone.top = innerString`;

Comment: It is no static block. A static block would be prefixed by **static**.

Comment: Ahh you are correct. But still, the problem remains.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the initializer block. You just do not instantiate the inner class. Place `new InnerClass();` in your main and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I figured it out.  Your solution and @manouti's both work fine.

Answer (score 0):

replace your `InnerClass` definition to

```
public static class InnerClass {

    public void setOuterClassTop() {
        String innerString = "bar";
        Ideone newOne = new Ideone();
        newOne.setTop(innerString );
    }

}
```

and it will work by calling the `setOuterClassTop()` method.